# IAsyncDisposable, IDisposable to dispose internal IAsyncDisposable member in a base class

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I am working with asp.net core signalR. I made a HubClientBase (which is a client for communicating with the signalR hub/server). It uses an HubConnection object to send/receive data in the derived classes.

```
    public abstract class HubClientBase : IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable
    {
        #region Properties and fields

        protected readonly ILogger<HubClientBase> Logger;
        protected readonly HubConnection Connection;

        #endregion
...
// Start connection
// Some other stuff
    }

// Derived:

 public class AlarmHubClient : HubClientBase, IAlarmHubClient, IAlarmHub
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public AlarmHubClient(ILogger<HubClientBase> logger, HubConnection connection)
            : base(logger, connection)
        {
        }

        protected override void AttachReceiveHandlers(HubConnection connection)
        {
            connection.On<AlarmBarMessageDto>(nameof(ReceiveCurrentAlarmBarMessage), ReceiveCurrentAlarmBarMessage);
            ...
        }

        #region Implementation of IAlarmHubClient

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public async Task SendCurrentAlarmBarMessage(AlarmBarMessageDto alarmBarMessage)
        {
            await Connection.SendAsync(nameof(SendCurrentAlarmBarMessage), alarmBarMessage);
        }
```

I run into 2 problems pertaining disposale however.

1. I use the client in a .NET 4.6.1 project. The dll gets loaded into a WPF application. This means, that .Dispose() is called by the UI thread. The hubconnection  only has a .DisposeAsync implementation, so i need to call that from the .Dispose method. We follow a hierachical dispose pattern, so i need to be sure the dispose is blocking until it is done. I however cannot `Wait()` in the dispose, since that would block the ui thread (a deadlock occurs, where the task will be scheduled to run on the main ui thread, but the thread cannot do any work because its waiting)

This means, I have to use Task.Run - which is far from an ideal solution...

```cs
 #region IDisposable

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (Connection != null)
                {
                    // Force the async method on the thread pool with Task.Run.
                    // WARN A library / base should 99.9% of the time never use Task.Run, since the creation of threads should be a responsibility of the application level.
                    Task.Run(async () => await Connection.DisposeAsync())
                        .ConfigureAwait(true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        #endregion
```

What would be a better way to go about Async disposing a member in the sync dispose?

1. I tried using IAsyncDisposable aswell, so I can maybe work some magic upstream and use that instead of Dispose(). I came up with the following, but i found ample documentation about how to correctly use IAsyncDispose. especially since this is a baseclass that will be derived from:

```cs
        #region Implementation of IAsyncDisposable

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                return new ValueTask(Connection.DisposeAsync());
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                return new ValueTask(Task.FromException(exc));
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

Is this a good way of async dispoing a member in the async dispose? Any recommendations for derived classes?

Comment: You can dispose it by wrapping a call into `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`, since it's called from WPF app. Btw, why do you need to call `Dispose`, why don't call just `DisposeAsync`? It returns a regular `ValueTask`

Comment: You can also use `DisposeAsync` as a wrapper for the regular `Dispose`, and call the correct method depending on the context (if you cam control `Connection` disposal)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski because we have a system in place that uses dispose (I don't get to call it - it gets called for me) that would mean some architectural changes. `Dispatcher.Invoke(class.DisposeAsync)` would mean the same as just calling  `class.DisposeAsync()` since it takes the main threads sync. context, which means it uses the WPF taskscheduler wich means it will be scheduled on the main thread - I reckon?

Comment: DisposeAsync does not get called at the moment, .Dispose() is. I would like the .Dispose() to work now, and then in some time i can invest the time to change our framework so it can support AsyncDispose - once i know all the details.

Comment: `Dispatcher` associated with UI thread and uses the main thread synchronization context, it's true. But I don't fully understand, what is the issue to make an async call in the main thread? there will be no deadlocks unless you make a blocking call, like `Wait()` or `Result`

Comment: Exactly - but i want it to block! Dispose() should block, if i have 4 objects i want to be sure obj1 is diposed before obj2 so i need it to be blocking.